# Special char jquery

Tags: html, jquery, datatable, special-characters, html-entities

I have a problem with `&gt;` and jquery datatable shows '>' fine but when I click on the row I get the character `&gt;` and I'm desperate.

Any solution?

```
$('#sample tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    //console.log(table.row(this).data());
    $(".modal-bodya div span").text("");
    $(".new span").text(dataTable.row(this).data()[2]);
```

Comment: use .html instead of .text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're using `text()`, which does not encode HTML entities. To get the output you expect use `html()` instead.

```js
let value = 'foo &gt; bar';

$(".text span").text(value);
$(".html span").html(value);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">Text: <span></span></div>
<div class="html">HTML: <span></span></div>
```